# Can one sell or donate breast milk in Islam?

Tags: practical-islam, mahram

In the west, we have milk banks where many women either sell or donate their breast milk

Given the fact that suckling five times makes a child mahram to the woman & also makes her own children siblings to that child, what is the ijtehad among the scholars on this issue?

Comment: Thw matter of five sucklings is not a consensus of scholars at least it wasn't al-Laith ibn Sa'ad even claimed consensus or agreement about one suckling beibg sufficient...However the point could get difficult if the milk of different women was mixed...

Comment: @Medi1Saif So can it be considered to be Makruh (disliked) at the very least, to sell breast milk not knowing which child will eventually drink it irrespective of the number of sucklings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Feeding breastmilk purchased from store](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49361/feeding-breastmilk-purchased-from-store)

Comment: its a matter of dispute and from what i have seen, the strongest evidence is on the side that it is not permissible. thought there are some who say its a matter of masyaqqah. but to me this whole concept is unislamic, selling and donating breast-milk. so why follow what is not from us?. (there are breast milk banks in some "islamic" countries).

Comment: Is there any post covering the minimum amount of breast feedings or sucklings for mahram relation according the scholarly opinions? If not it would be worth creating one in order to refer to it in future. All scholars would agree about five sucklings, as minimum for an agreement, but not for the absolute minimum as stated in my comment above. The only two madhhabs that agree on a minimum of 5 sucklings are shafi'i and hanbali AFAIK.

Answer (score -1):

When you send a child to someone for feeding, it is not very different (in essence) from selling or purchasing the milk( or rather) the services of another woman.

Besides, the issue of donating or selling one's blood to another is not a very different issue.